# Proof check. Well-ordering principle for the natural numbers.

Tags: proof-verification, induction, order-theory, well-orders

I know there are a lot of proofs out there for the well-ordering principle already. As an exercise, I thought I'd try to prove it differently. My attempt is as follows. Would appreciate any feedback!

Prove: Every non-empty subset of the natural numbers, S, has a minimum, min(S), such that min(S) is less than or equal to all s in S.

Let Sn denote a subset (of the natural numbers) of cardinality n.

(Base case) n = 1: S contains exactly one element, x. Clearly, x is less than or equal to all s in S.

(Inductive step) Suppose inductively that min(Sn) is well-defined. It can be shown that min(Sn+1) is also well-defined. In particular, Sn+1 can be written as Sn U S1. min(S1) and min(Sn) are both well-defined. There are three possible relationships between min(S1) and min(Sn): <, =, >. If min(S1) < min(Sn), then min(S1) is less than or equal to every element in S1 and Sn and is therefore less than or equal to every element in Sn+1. [Perform the same analysis on each of the two other cases]

QED

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](/help/notation),
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: WTF? I edit the tags, but they won't change.

Comment: Mods, [here](http://imgur.com/a/XnO8d)'s what happens on my screen. Note that there's no elementary-number-theory tag, but after my edit, it appears with no apparent reason. The gif is a bit long because this laptop is very slow.

Comment: Why should $S_{n+1} = S_n \cup S_1$? What about infinite subsets? What specific statement are you proving by induction?

Comment: @GitGud: There might be a good proof idea hiding in there, but the proof as written is very much not fine.

Comment: @Matt Sorry I mislead you, Hurkyl is correct.

Comment: @Hurkyl What I meant by that statement is that any set of cardinality n+1 can be written as the union of two sets - one of cardinality n and the other of cardinality 1

Comment: @Hurkyl I want to prove by induction that min(Sn) is defined for all n, where Sn is defined to be a set of cardinality n

Comment: @Matt Hurkyl's point is that that's not the same as proving that every non-empty subset of the natural numbers has a minimum. Consider for instance the set $\{n\in \mathbb N\colon n\ge 1000\}$.

Comment: I had two points, actually; the other point is that the usage of $S_n$ doesn't really make sense. I think that it's short hand for "some set with $n$ elements" rather than what the notation actually indicates. The $n=2$ case highlights the problem, since the decomposition would then become $S_2 = S_1 \cup S_1$, but the two different $S_1$'s denote different sets!

Comment: @Hurkyl Admittedly, the notation may have been sloppy. But I did intend Sn to mean exactly that - i.e., "some set with n elements"

Comment: @Git Gud Thank you for your feedback as well! I've posted a follow-up question relevant to your point in the comment section of Hurkyl's response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Often times, the problem people have with induction is that they don't have a clearly stated proposition they are using an inductive argument to prove.

Your attempt at the problem appears to be trying to prove the proposition

> $P_n \equiv$ Every subset of $n$ elements has a minimum

And to fix up your inductive step, start by saying something like

> Suppose $P_n$ is true. Let $S$ be a set of $n+1$ elements. Write $S = U \cup V$ where $U$ has $n$ elements and $V$ has $1$ element

Then use $U$ and $V$ everywhere you write $S_n$ and $S_1$.

Once you've done that... you may have a correct proof of $P_{n+1}$. But it's terse and missing many details. On the one hand, it's the sort of thing I'd accept from my colleagues because I think it's clear how to fill in the details (and I imagine it's also clear to my colleagues). But on the other hand, I'm not sure that I would accept it from a student who is learning about proofs and is having trouble with the details, because I strongly suspect that the details are omitted because they *don't* understand how to fill them in, and at best only understand the intuitive idea.

---

But let's say you do have a correct proof, so that by induction, $P_n$ holds for every $n$. This still doesn't prove the theorem you were trying to prove, however — you can conclude that every *finite* set has a minimum, but it still leaves open whether or not an *infinite* set has a minimum.

Ultimately, you need to mix in a *new idea* to complete the proof.

Comment: First of all, thanks so much for your feedback. Suppose I've shown that Pn holds for every n. Presumably, n is allowed to get infinitely large. So why would the scope of Pn be limited only to finite sets?

Comment: @Matt: No! $n$ is able to grow *arbitrarily large*, but it is always a *natural number*, and thus *finite*. There are forms of transfinite induction that can continue on to transfinite ordinals, but the approach you use is not one of those forms.

Comment: @Matt: For something more blunt, consider the statement $Q_n \equiv n \text{ is finite}$. Since adding one to a finite number gives a finite number, we can prove this by induction. But does that mean infinitely large numbers are finite? Or just that each natural number is finite?

Comment: @Hurkyl I'll be up voting your answer as soon as the tags get fixed.

Comment: @Hurkyl Ok, I'm going to do some research on why induction does not extend to infinity. I'm going to go ahead and accept your answer - will follow up with a revision!

Comment: @Matt: (it's usually better to post a new question, rather than revise an existing one -- especially if the revision will invalidate the existing answers)